# API python : neutron client common exceptions unauthorized

Tags: python, api, openstack

My neutronTest.py file

```
import getpass
from neutronclient.v2_0 import client

username = '#myUserName#'
password1 = getpass.getpass()
tenant_name = '#myTenantName#'
auth_url = 'https://keystone.#mydomain#.fr:5000/v3'

neutron = client.Client(username=username,
  password = password1,
  tenant_name = tenant_name,
  auth_url = auth_url,
)

netw = neutron.list_networks()
print(netw)
```

Its gives me this Error :

The Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pythonTest.py", line 17, in <module>
    netw=neutron.list_networks()
  File "/root/myEnv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 640, in list_networks
    **_params)
  File "/root/myEnv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 357, in list
    for r in self._pagination(collection, path, **params):
  File "/root/myEnv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 372, in _pagination
    res = self.get(path, params=params)
  File "/root/myEnv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 342, in get
    headers=headers, params=params)
  File "/root/myEnv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 319, in retry_request
    headers=headers, params=params)
  File "/root/myEnv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 270, in do_request
    resp, replybody = self.httpclient.do_request(action, method, body=body)
  File "/root/myEnv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neutronclient/client.py", line 158, in do_request
    self.authenticate_and_fetch_endpoint_url()
  File "/root/myEnv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neutronclient/client.py", line 123, in authenticate_and_fetch_endpoint_url
    self.authenticate()
  File "/root/myEnv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neutronclient/client.py", line 237, in authenticate
    self._authenticate_keystone()
  File "/root/myEnv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neutronclient/client.py", line 218, in _authenticate_keystone
    raise exceptions.Unauthorized(message=resp_body)
neutronclient.common.exceptions.Unauthorized: {"error": {"message": "The resource could not be found.", "code": 404, "title": "Not Found"}}
```

I think because I have a v3 keystone version, but I still don't know how to solve the problem.

Thank you for your help!